# Asynchronous channel close in Java NIO

Tags: java, asynchronous, nio

Suppose I have simple nio based java server. For example (simplified code):

```
while (!self.isInterrupted()) {
  if (selector.select() <= 0) {
    continue;
  }

  Iterator<SelectionKey> iterator = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    SelectionKey key = iterator.next();
    iterator.remove();
    SelectableChannel channel = key.channel();

    if (key.isValid() && key.isAcceptable()) {
      SocketChannel client = ((ServerSocketChannel) channel).accept();
      if (client != null) {
        client.configureBlocking(false);
        client.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
      }
    } else if (key.isValid() && key.isReadable()) {
      channel.read(buffer);
      channel.close();
    }
  }
}
```

So, this is simple single threaded non blocking server.

Problem reside in following code.

```
channel.read(buffer);
channel.close();
```

When I closing channel in same thread (thread that accept connection and reading data) all works fine. But I got a problem when connection closed in another thread. For example

```
((SocketChannel) channel).read(buffer);
executor.execute(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
     channel.close();
   }
});
```

In this scenario I ended up with socket in state TIME_WAIT on server and ESTABLISHED on client. So connection is not closing gracefully. Any ideas what's wrong? What I missed?

Comment: What the host OS?  This may be an implementation feature/bug as the package specs assert that these are all thread-safe constructs.

Comment: Host machine under Mac OS X 10.5.6. Today I'm repeat tests under windows 7 and it's work just fine. Seems like you are right.

Comment: What happens if you close channel.socket() before closing the channel?

Comment: For me it's all the same (at least on windows). If I call channel.socket().close(), channel becomes closed (with gracefull client disconnect).

Comment: Behavior is identical in 1.4, 1.5 and 1.6, at least on my Mac, so I suggest following my advice below and do it on the same thread. That strategy also has the virtue of simplifying other features you're likely to want to add to your server.

Comment: By the way, why do you need to close it from another thread?

Comment: It's the most simple way for me. I'm closing socket just after writing data to it. And writing is delegated in another thread.

Comment: That begs the question why you are writing in another thread.

Comment: All request dispatching is delegated to another thread. I know that there is more efficient way to process request (dispatching all channel activity in selector thread/threads using read/write queue for each channel). But my server is simply echo back server with some latency before reply. I use it for scalability testing of another application (proxy-server). And I try to keep it simple as much as I can.

Comment: By the way, are you sure that the connection never closes or does it just take time (about 1 min)? Have you tested on Linux?

Comment: TIME_WAIT is normal. Life in TCP/IP land.

Comment: No need to call `iterator.remove();` because each loop you're recreating the `Iterator` and calling `next()` will not return the same object twice.

Answer (score 1):

TIME_WAIT means the OS has received a request to close the socket, but waits for possible late communications from the client side. Client apparently didn't get the RST, since it's still thinks it's ESTABLISHED. It's not Java stuff, it's OS. RST is apparently delayed by OS -- for whatever reason.

Why it only happens when you close it in another thread -- who knows? May be OS believes that closes in another thread should wait for original thread exit, or something. As I said, it's OS internal mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it would make a difference unless the close is throwing an exception.  If it were you wouldn't see the exception.  I suggest putting the close in a catch(Throwable t) and print out the exception (assuming there is one)

Comment: I tried that. All key points in my code wrapped in try-catch with logging exception. No exception occur at this point. Before closing channel it is active, after close it is on CLOSED state (but socket in TIME_WAIT state).

Answer (score 0):

You know, after a bit more careful testing I cannot reproduce you results on my Mac.

While it is true that the connection remains in TIME_WAIT for something around 1 minute after close on the server side, it closes immediately on the client side (when I connect to it using a telnet client to test).

This is the same regardless of on what thread I close the channel. What machine are you running on and what version of java?

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with [the problem mentioned here](http://markmail.org/message/of4h63wogwhxpge5). If it really *is* the behaviour of the BSD / OS X poll() method I do think you're out of luck.

I think I would mark this code as non-portable due to - as I understand it - a bug in BSD / OS X.

Answer (score 0):

You have a major problem in your example.

With Java NIO, the thread doing the *accept()* **must** only be doing the *accept()*. Toy examples aside you are probably using Java NIO because of anticipated high number of connections. If you even *think* about doing the read in the same thread as the selects, the pending unaccepted selects will time out waiting for the connection to be established. By the time this one overwrought thread gets around to accepting the connection, the OS's on either side will have given up and the accept() will fail.

Only do the absolute minimum in the selection thread. Any more and you will just being rewriting the code until you do only the minimum.

*[In response to comment]*

Only in toy examples should the reading be handled on the main thread.

Try to handle:

- 300+ simultaneous connection attempts.
- Each connection once established sends 24K bytes to a single server - i.e. a small web page, a tiny .jpg.
- Slow down each connection slightly ( the connection is being established over a dialup, or the network is having a high-error/retry rate) - so the TCP/IP ACK takes longer than ideal (out of your control OS level thing)
- Have some of your test connections, send a single bytes every 1 milliseconds. (this simulates a client that is having its own high load condition, so is generating the data at a very slow rate.) The thread has to spend almost the same amount of effort processing a single bytes as it does 24K bytes.
- Have some connections be cut with no warning ( connection lost issues ).

As a practical matter, the connection needs to be established within 500ms -1500ms before the attempting machine drops the connection.

As a result of all these issues, a single thread will not be able to get all the connections set up fast enough before the machine on the other end gives up the connection attempt. The reads must be in a different thread. period.

**[Key Point]**
I forgot to really be clear about this. But the threads doing the reading will have their own Selector. The Selector used to establish the connection should not be used to listen for new data.

*Addition (in response to Gnarly's contention that no I/O actually occurs during the java call to read the stream.*

Each layer has a defined buffer size. Once that buffer is full, the IO is halted. For example, TCP/IP buffers have between 8K-64K buffers per connection. Once the TCP/IP buffer fills, the receiving computer tells the sending computer to stop. If receiving computer does not process the buffered bytes fast enough the sending computer will drop the connection.

If the receiving computer is processing the buffered bytes, the sender will continue to stream the bytes, *while the java io read call is being made*.

Furthermore, realize that the first byte to arrive triggers the "bytes available to be read" on the selector. There is no guarantee as to how many have arrived.

The buffer sizes defined in the java code have no relationship to the buffer size of the OS.

Comment: As far as I remember main thread should read data from socket. This reading is not blocking (data already ready for reading). If you delegating reading to the another thread you end up in situation where selector thread will wake up several times on the same event. This happens because of parallel thread probably will have not time to finish read before selector thread will do next select.

Comment: I disagree. If the server is setup in a non-blocking asynchronous manner than you shouldn't have to thread any I/O operations since it's **non-blocking**, meaning that the calling of the method itself does nothing more than make a simple call to the OS. It doesn't actually perform the I/O operation on the thread you made the call on. Also, multiple `Selector`s is the most pointless idea ever. A `Selector` can operate as fast as the OS will allow it to. Adding in multiples will only slow down the readiness selection of the other `Selector`s **if anything**.

Comment: @Gnarly - Using a single selector to handle setting up new connections AND processing existing connections will fail under any reasonable load. And yes IO can and does occur during the call. (See edit to main reply)

Comment: @Pat - Do you have any benchmarks to back up your claim? Unless you do, please do not say that you need multiple `Selector`s to have a stable server. Like I said before, a single `Selector` can virtually scale to an unlimited extent. I have years of heavy NIO server development and I know what I'm talking about. Also, you don't understand what asynchronous means do you? The I/O operation may occur during the call, but it **does not** block the thread that made the call - thus making it completely useless to pass the work onto a new thread.

Comment: @Gnarly -- ROTFL. Tell you what, you go first with your proof. And then read the circumstances that I laid out in my response, specifically, slow servers. And no, I am not going to jump through any hoops to "proof" this any more than anyone else does on this website.

Comment: Exactly what I expected, since you don't know what you're talking about you can't back up your claims. Might I suggest [Java NIO](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596002886) for you to read and hopefully learn something. I'm not going to argue with you since you're not even mature enough to handle a simple debate without trying to sound cocky. Go on and have fun with your multi-selector and multi-thread based asynchronous NIO designs.

Comment: @Gnarly - exactly the book I was referring to the got it wrong. Have a nice day. (BTW: I have been coding with Java NIO since it came out, and with Java since 1.0)

Comment: Gnarly is right, Pat is wrong - this answer seems to miss the whole point of async I/O in the first place.

Comment: Yawn. Didn't miss the point. Try creating a service that gets 3000 connections simultaneous connection attempts. Using the OP's code, you will lose connections. Have a nice day, but try the conditions I laid out first. Not some toy example in an out-of-date book. btw, I have this as a "Community Wiki" because its annoy to have people downrate a correct answer.